# R - Modify column value depending on first occurence of another column

Tags: r, row, multiple-columns

Suppose I have a file containing 2 columns similar to this one:

```
     ID   Order
      2       1
     10       2
     70       3
     85       4
     70       5
    213       6
      2       7
    293       8
     10       9
    313      10
    ...     ...
```

with `IDs` containing numbers between 1 and 1000, each appearing 4 times.
In `Order` there are numbers going from 1 to 4000.

Is it possible in R to modify the `Order` column, in a way that for the following 3 same IDs it replaces the `Order` by the `Order` corresponding to the first occurence? For the example data set it would for instance output the following:

```
     ID   Order
      2       1
     10       2
     70       3
     85       4
     70       3
    213       6
      2       1
    293       8
     10       2
    313      10
    ...     ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this using the `dplyr` library.  You can group by the ID and then use the `mutate` function to find the minimum Order for each ID.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Order = min(Order)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 x 2
      ID Order
   <int> <dbl>
 1     2     1
 2    10     2
 3    70     3
 4    85     4
 5    70     3
 6   213     6
 7     2     1
 8   293     8
 9    10     2
10   313    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
df$Order <- with(df, ave(Order, ID, FUN = `[`, 1))
```

data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, Order := Order[1], ID]


#      ID Order
#  1:   2     1
#  2:  10     2
#  3:  70     3
#  4:  85     4
#  5:  70     3
#  6: 213     6
#  7:   2     1
#  8: 293     8
#  9:  10     2
# 10: 313    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to filter the first occurrences, then rejoin to the full list of original IDs

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)

df <- read_table2(" ID   Order
      2       1
     10       2
     70       3
     85       4
     70       5
    213       6
      2       7
    293       8
     10       9
    313      10")

df %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(ID)) %>% 
  list(., df %>% select(ID)) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "ID")
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>       ID Order
#>    <int> <int>
#>  1     2     1
#>  2     2     1
#>  3    10     2
#>  4    10     2
#>  5    70     3
#>  6    70     3
#>  7    85     4
#>  8   213     6
#>  9   293     8
#> 10   313    10
```

Created on 2018-09-25 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).